What is the reference model in the MA component of an ARIMA model?
The MA component in ARIMA is defined as a model that predicts values from the residuals (errors) of lagged observations.
But, how are those residuals calculated?
Of course they are obtained as the difference between the real value and the predicted value.
But, from which model are those predictions coming from? Is it a moving average model that averages the last q observations?
Thanks in advance.

Hi: See Harvey's "econometric analysis of time series" for a clear explanation of the gory details behind the algorithm for fitting a model where the residuals are part of the model as is the case for an ARIMA model where q > 0. It's the clearest explanation of that sort of thing that I'm aware of. A very underrated text that I always recommend.

The residuals are coming from the same ARIMA model. They are calculated simultaneously as the model is fit. This is not a two-step procedure where (1) some model is fit and residuals are obtained and then (2) ARIMA model is fit using the residuals as inputs. This also means that you cannot use, say, ordinary least squares (OLS) to fit an ARIMA model with the moving-average lag order $q>0$, because the lagged residuals which are the required inputs into OLS are not given and cannot be obtained separately from estimating the ARIMA model. Therefore, estimation of an ARIMA model with $q>0$ is a complicated matter!
